# Python- load data on first instance of class

Tags: python

I have a python class that will need to reference a large data set. I need to create thousands of instances of the class so I don't want to load the data set every time. It would be straightforward to put the data in another class that has to be created first and passed to the other one as an argument:

```
class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # load dataset...

class Class_using_dataset():
    def __init__(self, ds)
        # use the dataset and do other stuff

ds = Dataset('file.csv')
c1 = Class_using_dataset(ds)
c2 = Class_using_dataset(ds)
# etc...
```

But I don't want my user to have to deal with the dataset since its always the same one if I can just do it in the background.

Is there a pythonic/canonical way to load the data into a global namespace when I create the first instance of my class? I'm hoping for something like:

```
class Class_using_dataset():
    def __init__(self):
        if dataset doesn't exist:
             load dataset into global namespace
        use dataset
```

Comment: Don't. Make `Class_using_dataset` a method of the dataset, or a classmethod of `Class` that takes a dataset. In either case you can take a closure or bound method to remove the cost, whilst keeping things local. Global variables are bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either load the dataset into a class variable at the time the `Class_using_dataset` class is parsed, or when the user creates the first instance of the class.

The first strategy simply requires you to move the line loading the dataset into the class itself.

```
class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # load dataset...

class Class_using_dataset():
    ds = Dataset('file.csv')

    def __init__(self)
        # use the dataset and do other stuff

# `Class_using_dataset.ds` already has the loaded dataset
c1 = Class_using_dataset()
c2 = Class_using_dataset()
```

For the second, assign `None` to the class variable, and only load the dataset in the `__init__` method if `ds` is `None`.

```
class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # load dataset...

class Class_using_dataset():
    ds = None

    def __init__(self)
        if Class_using_dataset.ds is None:
            Class_using_dataset.ds = Dataset('file.csv')
        # use the dataset and do other stuff

# `Class_using_dataset.ds` is `None`
c1 = Class_using_dataset()
# Now the dataset is loaded
c2 = Class_using_dataset()
```

Comment: When you use the second method, be sure to do the check with `is None` (as in the answer above) and not with `== None`. If you use `==`, then you might run into trouble if the dataset is a class that overloads the Equals operator. This happened to me with a dataset that was a numpy array, and my code raised a `ValueError`. Switching from `== None` to `is None` fixed it. Hopefully this might help someone else who made the same mistake as me.

Answer (score 1):

If the dataset is shared between all instances of the class, make it a class variable.

```
class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # load dataset...

class Class_using_dataset():
    def __init__(self)
        # use the dataset and do other stuff

Class_using_dataset.ds = Dataset('file.csv')
c1 = Class_using_dataset()
c2 = Class_using_dataset()
# etc...
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a variation where the user doesn't have to see it at all? In your version, it looks like it would just load the file at the line where you explicitly set it. If I load it inside the class, does that load every time an instance is created or just once?

Comment: If you put it inside the class, _before_ the `__init__`, it'll only load it once. Give it a try (with a simple `print()` in the `Dataset` class) and see.